# Using matrix functions for colorplot in Python

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a pcolormesh where z is a function of the (axis) variables x and y. The function z is a module I've written that uses matrices with elements dependent on x and y and returns a an element of the final matrix (a number between 0 and 1). When I tried to run this I get the error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

How do I define z as a function that uses x and y in a matrix. Here is the code I'm running. I haven't included the NewATFS module but its essentially just some matrix multiplication and returns a specific element of the final matrix.
    state = matrix( [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] )
    dx, dy = 0.5, 1

```
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(1, 170 + dy, dy),
            slice(0.5, 5 + dx, dx)]
z = NewATFS.ATFS(state, 1.25, 0.01, y, 1, 0.25, 0.125, 1, x, 1, 10, True)
z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
plt.title('pcolormesh')
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar()
```